# While loop not satisfying both conditions

Tags: php, while-loop, conditional-statements

I have a script to get information from a database and check it using a while loop to certain conditions. The first of these conditions is always met but the second is not.
Here is the code I am using:

```
//Get the new ad's id
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT visits, description, url, views, time FROM paidAds WHERE id=? AND finished!=?");
    //Bind Items
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $currentAd, $adFinished);
    //Execute statement
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    //Bind password to variable
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $adVisits, $adDescription, $adUrl, $adViews, $adTime);
    //Fetch password
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
    //Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

    //Get the new ad's id
    $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT ip FROM adViews WHERE adId=? AND address=?");
    //Bind Items
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, 'is', $currentAd, $address);
    //Execute statement
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
    //Bind password to variable
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2, $userIp);
    //Fetch password
    mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt2);
    //Close statement
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt2);

    if($stmt2 === false){
        echo mysqli_error($db);
    }

    while($adDescription == '' && $userIp != ''){
        $currentAd += 1;

        //Get the new ad's id
        $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT visits, description, url, views, time FROM paidAds WHERE id=? AND finished!=?");
        //Bind Items
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ii', $currentAd, $adFinished);
        //Execute statement
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        //Bind password to variable
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $adVisits, $adDescription, $adUrl, $adViews, $adTime);
        //Fetch password
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
        //Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

        //Get the new ad's id
        $stmt2 = mysqli_prepare($db, "SELECT ip FROM adViews WHERE adId=? AND address=?");
        //Bind Items
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt2, 'is', $currentAd, $address);
        //Execute statement
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt2);
        //Bind password to variable
        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt2, $userIp);
        //Fetch password
        mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt2);
        //Close statement
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt2);

        if($userIp != ''){
            echo 'error';
        }
    }

    echo $userIp;
```

The output of this script does not display any 'error's as it should, but when printing the variable $userIp it is not empty.
Why is this?

Comment: why are you doing the same queries before the loop that you are doing inside the loop? There must be a `JOIN` query that you could do that would prevent the 4 queries you are currently trying to do.

Comment: The first queries are to get the initial variables to check against in the loop. I will look into JOIN queries, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you're using

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $adVisits, $adDescription, $adUrl, $adViews, $adTime);
```

before the program has entered the while loop. So $adDescription != '' and the program doesn't enter the loop.

Comment: I can't say I'm quite sure what you mean. Could you perhaps give an example order of what things should go in?

Comment: You're assigning a value to $adDescription so it isn't == ' ' and the program will not enter the while loop. I think you should try removing $adDescription == '' as a condition from the while loop cause I don't actually know the reason of this condition.

Comment: The first value of $adDescription is possible to be blank if the column 'finished' is equal to 1 in the database. If the value of $adDescription isn't blank, will the while loop not run, despite not satisfying the second condition?